# Flow simulation multi plot

Tags: matlab

I am proper stuck on plotting a graph.

It's a graph of flow simulation, I need to be able to see the graphs for about 25 time segments between t=0 and t=1.

this is the code I've written that does it for t=0.1. I obviously can't repeat the code 25 times. Is there any way of programming it to plot all in one go. i.e using loop?

ALSO, I need to redefine both the axis to go from 0 to 1.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=linspace(0,1,25)
for k=1:length(t)

  A=(a1^2*P)/(i*mu*L*alpha^2)

  B1=i^1.5*alpha*r/a1

  B2=i^1.5*alpha

  B11=besselj(0,B1)

  B22=besselj(0,B2)

  B=1-(B11/B22)

  C=exp(i*w*t(k))

  u=real(A*B*C)

  plot(u,r,u,-r)
  drawnow
end
```

use `drawnow` after your plot command. this will force matlab to draw the plot immediately, enabling you to see the progress of the simulation.

EDIT:
I didn't see the last bit. To set your x & y axis to go from 0 to 1, do `xlim([0 1])` and `ylim([0 1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. let me have a go.

Comment: Hiya, thanks alot. The last bit makes the graph disappear. Is there anyway to rescale it?

Comment: what do you mean disappear? if your plot extends outside the limits [0 1], and you use the xlim and ylim settings i gave, then it will definitely clip your plot. 

if you wanted to rescale `u` and `r` both to be between 0 and 1 (or -1 and 1, if it includes negative numbers), then do

u1=u/max(abs(u));
r1=r/max(abs(r));
plot(u1,r1)